# Is there a limit to the size of a struct array in c

Tags: c, windows, memory, mingw

So I am making a text based game and I have encountered an issue. I have made a map of 101 by 101 of the following `struct` elements for each tile:

```c
struct tile
{
    char name[21];
    short id;
    char description[100];
}; //End tile struct
```

This takes up just over 1MB of memory. If I change the size of the map to 103 by 103, then it works fine; but, if I change it to 151 by 151, the program crashes when I try to enter my save function.

Is there a reason for this and, if so, can I fix it?

I am running the a 64-bit system so, as far as I am aware, pointers should be able to address everything properly but perhaps I am wrong.

**EDIT**: A function to reproduce this would be:

```c
int main()
{
    struct tile map[151][151];

    mapGen(map);

} //End main
```

What the `mapGen` function does doesn't really matter, as that isn't the problem. I have been told that the stack can only hold 1MB of memory and, as soon as it tries to load `main` (or `save()`, in my case) it crashes the program.

Comment: Is this a local variable? The stack size on Windows is [1MB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-stack-size).

Comment: This is certainly a local variable. But having huge local arrays in most likely poor design. You need to tell us more.

Comment: Please make a little more *complete* example.

Comment: Yes it is and I am passing it between functions. Is there a way around this? I could use it as a global struct but my project is split in to multiple files so I am not sure how to do that across multiple files.

Comment: If you want more info you are going to have to let me know what you want/need to know as otherwise I am unsure of what else to tell you

Comment: @PaulGeoghegan What Antti is requesting is a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Because the array is defined at block scope, it resides on the stack.  Given the size of your array, it will take up around 2.8MB of space which is more than most stack implementation allow.  This results in a stack overflow which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you move the array outside of any function so it has file scope, it will instead reside in the data section which can handle a variable of that size.  You can also leave it at block scope and use the `static` modifier which also puts the variable in the data section and gives it full program lifetime.

You can also allocate space for it dynamically on the heap:

```
struct tile (*map)[151] = malloc(sizeof(*map) * 151);
```